Play audio with controls from wordpress to flutter page
I am trying to play audio from wordpress on my flutter app page using flutter_html and just_audio
I have tried the below but still I can not see any audio controls show up on the page
below my whole page content, I have tried also to install WP plugins for audio and same issue audio not appearing on the page
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';



class _ContentPageState extends State<ContentPage> {

  final AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _audioPlayer.dispose(); // Dispose the audio player
    super.dispose();
  }

 
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: Html(
                  data: """
                    <div>${widget.content}</div>
                  """,
                  style: {
                    "h1": Style(
                      fontSize: FontSize(_fontSize),
                      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 10, 93), // Title color
                      fontFamily: 'myfont',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      direction: TextDirection.rtl,
                    ),
                    "div": Style(
                      fontSize: FontSize(_fontSize),
                      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0), // Content color
                      lineHeight: LineHeight(1.6),
                      direction: TextDirection.rtl,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  },
                  onLinkTap: (url, attributes, element) {
                    if (url != null && (url.endsWith('.mp3') || url.endsWith('.wav'))) {
                      _playAudio(url);
                    }


  Future<void> _playAudio(String url) async {
    try {
      await _audioPlayer.setUrl(url);
      _audioPlayer.play();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error playing audio: $e");
    }
  }
}


